# Javascript translation script improvement

Tags: javascript, translation

I have read few articles about this topic and few SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717475/how-to-translate-into-other-languages-my-web-page) but nothing really fit to my situation.

So basically I'm creating simple one-page app almost without any javascript involved. Very only place where I need JS is this translation. Generally it's not a problem for me to create some script in JS to translate so I did like this:

I'm importing two files into my index.html:

```
<script src="js/text.js"></script>
<script src="js/translator.js"></script>
```

In **text.js** I have constant object containing texts for website to display:

```
// Global constant "text" accessible in translator.js file
const text = {
    PL: {
        aboutHeading: "Kilka słów o mnie"
    },
    ENG: {
        aboutHeading: "Few words about me"
    }
};
```

In **translator.js** I have object responsible for checking which language and filling divs / headings / whatever of text:

```
// global translator object
const translator = {
    currentLanguage: '',
    checkLanguage() {
        switch (window.navigator.language) {
            case 'pl':
            case 'pl-PL': {
                this.currentLanguage = 'pl';
                break;
            }
            case 'en': {
                this.currentLanguage = 'eng';
                break;
            }
            default: {
                this.currentLanguage = 'eng';
                break;
            }
        }
        //alert(this.currentLanguage);
        //alert(window.navigator.language);
    },
    fillText(lang) {
        if(lang === 'pl') {
            document.getElementById('few-words-about-me-header').innerHTML = text.PL.aboutHeading;
            alert('inserted pl');
        }
        if(lang === 'eng') {
            document.getElementById('few-words-about-me-header').innerHTML = text.ENG.aboutHeading;
            alert('inserted eng');
        }
    },
};

translator.checkLanguage();
translator.fillText(translator.currentLanguage);

document.getElementById('polish-flag').addEventListener('click', () => {
    translator.fillText('pl');
});
document.getElementById('english-flag').addEventListener('click', () => {
    translator.fillText('eng');
});
```

Generally everything is working as expected, the only thing I'm worried about is that I've got two global variables here and I'm not really sure what to do about it. I feel like I can do this translation in some more efficient, prettier way.

So questions are - if it's okey to have this two global variables and if I can achieve same as above code in some prettier way?

Comment: Well, if you're going to have some sort of translator script, it's pretty much inevitable that you'll have global variables. It's good to reduce how many of those you have but it's also not really always feasible for them to be zero. With that said, you could avoid it in your case if you make the script run only once on page load. Still, I would probably not worry about it. You might be better off looking into a library for translations like [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/), so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply encapsulate both in an IIFE in a single script so that nothing pollutes the global namespace.

```
// main.js
(() => {
  const text = {
    PL: {
      aboutHeading: "Kilka słów o mnie"
    },
    ENG: {
      aboutHeading: "Few words about me"
    }
  };
  const translator = {
    currentLanguage: '',
    checkLanguage() {
      switch (window.navigator.language) {
        case 'pl':
        case 'pl-PL':
          {
            this.currentLanguage = 'p';
            break;
          }
        case 'en':
          {
            this.currentLanguage = 'eng';
            break;
          }
        default:
          {
            this.currentLanguage = 'eng';
            break;
          }
      }
      //alert(this.currentLanguage);
      //alert(window.navigator.language);
    },
    fillText(lang) {
      if (lang === 'pl') {
        document.getElementById('few-words-about-me-header').innerHTML = text.PL.aboutHeading;
        alert('inserted pl');
      }
      if (lang === 'eng') {
        document.getElementById('few-words-about-me-header').innerHTML = text.ENG.aboutHeading;
        alert('inserted eng');
      }
    },
  };

  translator.checkLanguage();
  translator.fillText(translator.currentLanguage);

  document.getElementById('polish-flag').addEventListener('click', () => {
    translator.fillText('pl');
  });
  document.getElementById('english-flag').addEventListener('click', () => {
    translator.fillText('eng');
  });
})();
```

If you have to create the `text` dynamically for some reason, you can avoid creating a global variable there by using `<script type="application/json">` instead, which is parseable but not automatically added to the global namespace. For example:

```html
<div></div>
<script type="application/json">{"foo": "foo", "bar": "bar"}</script>
<script>
(() => {
  const text = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('script[type="application/json"]').textContent);
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = text.foo + ' / ' + text.bar;
})();
</script>
```

You can also use object lookups to simplify the `currentLanguage` setting. `switch` statements are often too wordy and error-prone, compared to the alternative:

```
checkLanguage() {
  const languages = {
    pl: ['pl', 'pl-PL'],
    en: ['eng'],
  };
  const navigatorLanguage = window.navigator.language;
  const foundLanguageObj = Object.entries(languages)
    .find(([setting, arr]) => arr.includes(navigatorLanguage));
  this.currentLanguage = foundLanguageObj ? foundLanguageObj[0] : 'eng';
}
```

Comment: Can I have object inside `<script type="application/json">` like this one in question *text.js* ? I generally like the idea of putting translator.js into IIFE but I would like to separate text.js file from translator.js file

Comment: What inside the `application/json` in my example *is* an object - you can replace it with whatever you want. (it could also be an array, or a primitive)

Comment: I mean I changed type to application/json when importing text.js in index.html and now I'm trying to console log this object from translator.js like this : `console.log(document.querySelector('script[type="application/json"]').textContent);` but it's consoling empty string, I tried `.value` instead of textContent with no luck.

Comment: And since it's empty string I can't JSON.parse it

Comment: To use `application/json` you have to have it populated *on the page itself* like I did in the snippet, not in an external file. If you can't alter the page, another option would be to make a network request, eg `fetch('js/text.js').then(res => res.json()).then(text => { /* do stuff with text */ })`

Comment: Clear. Thank you.